# Enabled modules doesn't show on homepage Prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have installed a theme in prestashop 1.6 in which a particular module is  enabled by default, but doesn't show on home page.

I want to show that module on home page. How can I do that?
It is shown under header in module positions.

Comment: have you cleared the site cache? also, some modules might not show if they are coded to not show in certain conditions. ex: a promotion modules that if no promotions are set will return empty instead of the "no promotions at the moment".

Answer (score 1):

Please check your enable modules registered hook. May be these module are not registered `displayHome` hook. That why its not appear on home page.

Please register your home page displayable module to `displayHome` hook. Then it will be appear on Home page.

Comment: The module is hooked to two hooks: displayHome and Header. but it is not showing anywhere in my homepage.

Comment: What type of module is it? Should it have displaying features? Some do not on the front. Hooks are generally how you display them if they do.